# Timezone awareness TypeError in Django app with MongoDB backend

Tags: django, mongodb, timezone, typeerror

In my Django app for which I'm using MongoDB for backend, I'm getting the following error when I load a page,

```
can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

The relevant code seems to be,

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
```

I'm not sure how to make them comparable. Help?

Comment: My guess is that you have `USE_TZ` equal to `True`, and that your MongoDB backend isn't producing a timezone-aware `datetime` for `self.pub_date`. (Or vice versa.)

Comment: I've set 'USE_TZ' to True in my settings.py. Is there some way for me to make self.pub_date timezone-aware?

Comment: Can you give us the line that defines the pub_date field?

Comment: pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

Comment: Although setting USE_TZ to False in settings.py seems to have fixed it.